# SSIS script task soap web service call error

Tags: c#, web-services, soap, ssis

I am calling a soap based web service inside a SSIS script task. The web service requires a user name, password and a guid to work. Previous to calling a web service from a SSIS script task I have called a web service from a console application with success.
This is my C sharp code:

```
public void Main()
        {
            // TODO: Add your code here

                        // TODO: Add your code here
            MessageBox.Show((string)Dts.Variables["ServiceDateStart"].Value);

            string userName = "xxx";
            string password = "xxx";
            string licenceID = "xxx";
            ServiceReference.AuthenticationHeader a = new ServiceReference.AuthenticationHeader();
            a.LicenceID = new Guid(licenceID);
            a.UserName = userName;
            a.Password = password;
            ServiceReference.CompanyAccountXmlServiceSoapClient service = new ServiceReference.CompanyAccountXmlServiceSoapClient();

            string result;
            long numberOfResults;
            int counter1 = 0;
            int counter2 = 19;



            do
            {



               result = service.GetCompanyAccountUpdated(a, (string)Dts.Variables["ServiceDateStart"].Value, (string)Dts.Variables["ServiceDateEnd"].Value, counter1, counter2);
               //result = service.GetCompanyAccountUpdated(a, "20150101", "20150107", counter1, counter2);
                counter1 = counter1 + 20;
                counter2 = counter2 + 20;



                using (System.IO.StreamWriter file =
      new System.IO.StreamWriter(@"C:\Users\jkrneta\Documents\GetCompanyAccountUpdated.txt", true))
             {


                 file.WriteLine(result);


             }

            } while (!result.Equals("<CompanyAccountDataSet />"));


            Dts.TaskResult = (int)ScriptResults.Success;
        }
```

The code fails on line where I call the web service :

```
ServiceReference.CompanyAccountXmlServiceSoapClient service = new ServiceReference.CompanyAccountXmlServiceSoapClient();
```

This is my app.config file :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<configuration>
    <system.serviceModel>
        <bindings>
            <basicHttpBinding>
                <binding name="CompanyAccountXmlServiceSoap">
                    <security mode="Transport" />
                </binding>
                <binding name="CompanyAccountXmlServiceSoap1" />
            </basicHttpBinding>
        </bindings>
        <client>
            <endpoint address="https://webservices.nbs.rs/CommunicationOfficeService1_0/CompanyAccountXmlService.asmx"
                binding="basicHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="CompanyAccountXmlServiceSoap"
                contract="ServiceReference.CompanyAccountXmlServiceSoap" name="CompanyAccountXmlServiceSoap" />
        </client>
    </system.serviceModel>
</configuration>
```

The error that I get when I run the service in the debug mode is :

> Could not find default endpoint element that references contract
>   'ServiceReference.CompanyAccountXmlServiceSoap' in the ServiceModel
>   client configuration section. This might be because no configuration
>   file was found for your application, or because no endpoint element
>   matching this contract could be found in the client element.

What is needed to make my SSIS web service from script work?
Regards.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use this way:

```
ServiceReference.CompanyAccountXmlServiceSoapClient service = 
new  ServiceReference.CompanyAccountXmlServiceSoapClient("CompanyAccountXmlServiceSoap");
```

Other option is:

```
Reload the service reference of your project.
```

Just giving you an idea:

In my own experienced I do setting up an endpoint address to my code behind like this:

```
service.Endpoint.Address = new System.ServiceModel.EndpointAddress("https://webservices.nbs.rs/CommunicationOfficeService1_0/CompanyAccountXmlService.asmx");
```

Comment: Hi, I tried with both of the proposals but got the same errors...I will try to manually set the web service, see if that works...

Answer (score 0):

The problem is Script Task does not entertain app.config, so your config is not getting into play. Please try setting all components within the code, like below:

```
            EndpointAddress endpointAdress = new 
 EndpointAddress("https://webservices.nbs.rs/CommunicationOfficeService1_0/CompanyAccountXmlService.asmx");
            BasicHttpBinding binding1 = new BasicHttpBinding();
            binding1.Security.Mode = BasicHttpSecurityMode.Transport;
            var client = new ServiceReference.CompanyAccountXmlServiceSoapClient(binding1, endpointAdress);
```

If the client gets created fine then you are good to go.